# Why does form.$valid check non-required fields validity?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

In my AngularJS form, I have a few fields that are required and one field that is not. I want to prevent the submission of the form if the form is invalid, but when I checked `form.$valid` it always returns false, unless I provide valid input for the one non-required field (as well as all the others). Is there a way to make `form.$valid` return true only for required fields?

Some more detail:

```
<form novalidate name="contactForm" data-ng-submit="submit(contactForm)">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="f_name" name="name" required>
    <input type="email" data-ng-model="f_email" name="email" required>
    <input type="url" data-ng-model="f_url" name="url">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And my Controller:

```
app.controller('formController', function($scope){
    // Defaults
    $.extend( $scope, {
        f_name: 'NAME',
        f_email: 'EMAIL',
        f_url: 'URL',
        submit: function(form){
            alert(form.$valid); // Returns false even with valid name and email
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a field has data - it will be validated.

"Require" is only used to make sure the field is not empty.

Imagine you have an email input and the user enters an invalid address. You must validate it or you'll be using an invalid address in your code.

If you want to skip a specific field validation, you might want to write a method in your controller to do it.

Comment: Is there any directive to not count or disable validation for one input field then, without having to write custom validation?

Comment: Since you only need to validate two fields, I think a simple solution will be:
contactForm.name.$valid && contactForm.email.$valid